# Getting different resultset based on data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I have a table tbl_item in which item_id is varchar. when i use the queries below 1 get different results.

1. select * from tbl_item where item_id between 1 and 100 order by item_id
2. select * from tbl_item where item_id between '1' and '100' order by item_id

Since item_id data type is varchar so query 2 seems the right one but produces wrong result. It only lists items with item_id 1

Why is there this descrepancy in the results?

Comment: Should return '1', '10' and '100'. But why do you store id's in a varchar column?!? What's wrong with integer?

Comment: That is because when you store numbers as strings you will get sorting and logical checks done by how strings are sorted. With your first query you are getting an implicit conversion to int so the results are probably what you expect. Store your data in the proper datatype and this issue fixes itself.

Comment: @jarlh ......in the example I am using item id as 1 and 100 but in reality it can be something like 11234xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping. I found the correct way to get this done. The query below was initially giving some issues, don't know why but now it works.

```
select * from tbl_item where item_id>='1' and item_id<='100' order by item_id
```

Answer (score 1):

String comparison is not the same as integer comparison.  For instance, this is how the first 100 numbers look when ordered as strings:

```
1
10
100
11
12
. . .
```

The same thing is happening with `between`.  Because you have single quotes around the constants, the database engine decides that you really mean strings.  So, it interprets the values as strings.

Presumably, the first is the right way to express the query.  If the values are numbers, then use numbers for the comparison.

Comment: To add to how strings sort and Gordon's fine answer. The strings 2, 3,4 ,5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 would all get missed when using between '1' and '100'.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_item WHERE item_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100 ORDER BY item_id::INT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl_item where item_id between 1 and 100 order by cast(item_id as int)
```

Comment: casting would not work if the item id is alphanumeric like 1234xyz

Comment: You can use try_convert or try_cast if item_id is alphanumeric (SQL Server 2012 or above)